# Problems with package renaming in Mercurial project

Tags: java, mercurial, content-management-system, package, renaming

I have been using Mercurial for a while in my Java project. I work in a two man team. When I do merges, I find that file renaming has not caused many problems, but package renaming has caused major issues. Is this a known problem? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: did the merge success without error?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what sort of issues you're seeing.  Are you talking about renaming the directory (which, even though Mercurial doesn't track directories is special cased to work great) or that you have to manually merge in package change lines in every file (which I wouldn't expect either).  Without detailing your issues no one can help you.

Comment: When I ran into this problem, the merge was pretty painless. I can't remember all the details. It seemed like Mercurial didn't have merge conflicts with any of the package change lines.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the hg commands to do this?
You shouldn't  move files/directories without using hg.

Use hg move to move files/directories or "hg mv --after" to record a name that has already changed before.